# Moving data between separate physical drives

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, storage, storage-spaces

I have two main drives on my laptop, C-drive (100GB) and D-Drive(1TB). My C-drive has become very full and I have not managed to be able to move files and applications stored on the c-drive over to the d-drive. They are both separate physical drives as partitioning does not work. Is it possible that I can move storage space from the d-drive to c-drive some other way? If not, please can you let me know how I can move the files over without just creating a new shortcut.
I am on Windows 10

Comment: Personal files can be moved easily.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia , a vast majority of my personal files are very low in size, so they do not impact the total storage used up by much. I need to be able to move larger files such as the videos file, and applications

Comment: Video files are personal files. The OS and installed software didn; t create nor need them. Most applications in Windows can be installed in a different drive but if they're currently running from a SSD you'll notice much less performance when installed in a HDD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My C Drive is full without reason](https://superuser.com/questions/1433475/my-c-drive-is-full-without-reason)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have too much Temporary files junk so just open file explorer, copypaste this in the address box: `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp` and see what's in there... you can safely delete anything.

Comment: I typed that in, but I couldnt find anything larger than 16mb, and there is still 52 gb according to the storage application

Comment: I'd recommend you to use one out of these 3 programs that can scan your drive and tell you the size of every folder: [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) / [SpaceSniffer](https://www.fosshub.com/SpaceSniffer.html) / [TreeSize](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/index.shtml)